# How to ignore duplicate values while using concatenateif in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I work on Microsoft Excel with a lot of data, especially Manufacturing date(MFD) and Batch No.

A date can have number of entries, possibilities of the entries be similar or different. for example,

```
MFD             B.No.   
05-Apr-18   AD0418BB05    
05-Apr-18   AD0418BB05    
06-Apr-18   AD0418BB06    
06-Apr-18   AD0418BB06    
07-Apr-18   AA0418BB07    
07-Apr-18   BB0418BB07
```

I tried consolidating the dates in another column, using the formula ,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$15), 0)),"")
```

In the next column, i used concatenateif formula to concatenate the values corresponding to each date. the code is as follows,

```
=CONCATENATEIF($A$2:$A$15, D2, $B$2:$B$15, ",")
```

The output that i get is,

```
MFD         B.No.   
05-Apr-18   AD0418BB05,AD0418BB05    
06-Apr-18   AD0418BB06,AD0418BB06    
07-Apr-18   AA0418BB07,BB0418BB07
```

On `07-Apr-18`, it is great. But, on `05-Apr-18` AND `06-Apr-18`, two similar entries are concatenated. I want it be displayed only once. Have anyone got any ideas what I should do?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. : I can't carry out remove duplicates option, as i have many data related to this!!

Comment: Why not copy over the two columns to a new worksheet, and do remove duplicates there?

Comment: Luuklag, I have a very large database, performing remove duplicates for every time may not be feasible, that is why seeked some other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your concatenate function for this.

I introduced a `AllowDuplicates` parameter to choose if duplicates should be concatenated or not.

So use it like `=CONCATENATEIF($A$2:$A$15, D2, $B$2:$B$15, ",", FALSE)` to have no duplicates.

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, _
                       Condition As Variant, _
                       ConcatenateRange As Range, _
                       Optional Separator As String = ",", _
                       Optional AllowDuplicates As Boolean = True) As Variant

    Dim strResult As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
        ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
        If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
            If AllowDuplicates Then
                strResult = strResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
            Else
                If Not dict.Exists(ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value) Then
                    dict.Add ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value, 0
                    strResult = strResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If

    ConcatenateIf = strResult
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This code puts , if there is no value in cells here is its solution
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-concatenateif-function-trying-to-remove-duplicates.977125/

It shows blank if no value is there instead of showing ,,,,

```
Function ConcatIf(ByVal compareRange As Range, ByVal xCriteria As Variant, Optional ByVal stringsRange As Range, _
Optional Delimiter As String, Optional NoDuplicates As Boolean) As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With compareRange.Parent
    Set compareRange = Application.Intersect(compareRange, Range(.UsedRange, .Range("a1")))
End With
If compareRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
If stringsRange Is Nothing Then Set stringsRange = compareRange
Set stringsRange = compareRange.Offset(stringsRange.Row - compareRange.Row, _
stringsRange.Column - compareRange.Column)
 
For i = 1 To compareRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To compareRange.Columns.Count
        If (Application.CountIf(compareRange.Cells(i, j), xCriteria) = 1) Then
            If InStr(ConcatIf, Delimiter & CStr(stringsRange.Cells(i, j))) <> 0 Imp Not (NoDuplicates) Then
                ConcatIf = ConcatIf & Delimiter & CStr(stringsRange.Cells(i, j))
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
ConcatIf = Mid(ConcatIf, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
```

End Function